# Problem with Foreign Key in @OneToOne annotation

Tags: java, persistence, jpa

I have spent a couple of days with a weird problem. There is a plethora of similar posts here in StackOverflow and I have check a lot of them but I was unable to find something similar with this. I have a `Human` Parent class

```
import javax.persistence.*;
import java.util.Date;

@Entity(name = "Human")
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.TABLE_PER_CLASS)
public abstract class Human
{
    @Id
    @Column(name = "human_id", nullable = false)
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
    private Long id;

    @JsonProperty("name")
    private String name;

    @JsonProperty("date_of_birth")
    private Date dateOfBirth;

    @Embedded
    @JsonProperty("authentication_credential")
    private AuthenticationCredentials authCred;

    // constructors + setter/getters
}
```

A `User` child class :

```
import javax.persistence.*;
import java.util.Date;

@Entity(name = "User")
@Table(name = "end_user")
public class User extends Human
{
    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "user",
              cascade = CascadeType.ALL,
              fetch = FetchType.LAZY,
              optional = false)
    @JsonProperty("contact_numbers")
    private CollectionOfContactMethods contactNumbers;

    @JsonProperty("telephone")
    private String telephone;

    // constructors + setter/getters
 }
```

and also a `CollectionOfContactMethods` with composition relationship with the `User`.

```
import javax.persistence.*;
import java.util.List;

@Entity(name = "CollectionOfContactMethods")
@Table(name = "collection_of_contact_methods")
public class CollectionOfContactMethods
{
    @Id
    @Column(name = "collection_id", nullable = false)
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
    private Long id;

    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "ext_human_id", referencedColumnName = "human_id")
    private User user;

    @JsonProperty("email")
    private String email;

    // constructors + setter/getters
}
```

The plan, according to the ER diagram is this :

[image]

However, what I get at a database level is this :

[image]

I appreciate the time you spent. Thanks.

PS : Here is the `UserController`

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("api/v1/user/")
public class UserController
{
    @Autowired
    UserService userService;

    @GetMapping(value = "users")
    Iterable<User> list()
    {
        Iterable<User> retVal = userService.findAll();
        return retVal;
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "user", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    User create(@RequestBody User user)
    {
        return userService.save(user);
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "user/{id}",  method = RequestMethod.GET )
    Optional<User> get(@PathVariable Long id)
    {
        return userService.findById(id);
    }
}
```

and also `UserService` :

```
import com.tsakirogf.schedu.model.human.User;
import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;

public interface UserService extends CrudRepository<User, Long>
{
}
```

Comment: Have you tried dropping `referencedColumnName` as follows: `@JoinColumn(name = "ext_human_id")`*

Comment: Thanks a lot for the reply @JoãoDias. Unfortunately, this didn't help.

Comment: Have you tried dropping `Human` class and use only `User`? I know this is not what you need but just for debugging purposes and trying to figure out where the problem might be. Currently, there are too many moving parts.

Comment: @JoãoDias that, didn't help either.

Comment: And what about `@OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, optional = false)` in `CollectionOfContactMethods` instead of `@OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)`?

Comment: If this does not work either, can you please add the code that actually creates and persists the `User`?

Comment: @JoãoDias that will cause `not-null property references a null or transient value : com.tsakirogf.schedu.model.CollectionOfContactMethods.user`

Comment: Have you cleared your DB first?

Comment: It's H2 for now. I think it's not persistent. Every time I restart the app it gets purged.

Comment: Then can you add the code that creates the entities and persists them?

Comment: @JoãoDias Do you mean Controller and Service?

Comment: Yes, and the Repository as well. Thanks.

Comment: I have to thank you.

Comment: @JoãoDias This is it. Forgot to say I am using Spring Rest & Crud. So nothing really special there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have a bi-directional relationship between `User` and `CollectionOfContactMethods`, the issue might be that `CollectionOfContactMethods` `user` is null when you try to create it, hence the null data in the database or the `not-null property references a null or transient value : com.tsakirogf.schedu.model.CollectionOfContactMethods.user` error. Try the following:

```java
@RequestMapping(value = "user", method = RequestMethod.POST)
User create(@RequestBody User user) {
    CollectionOfContactMethods contactNumbers = user.getContactNumbers();
    contactNumbers.setUser(user);
    user.setContactNumbers(contactNumbers);
    return userService.save(user);
}
```

Comment: This worked for me, but triggered this : https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-bidirectional-relationships-and-infinite-recursion. The solution was a set of @JsonManagedReference/@JsonBackReference